# Symfony new field type

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I wanted add custom field type to form. It seems like alias not working:

## bundle_dir/services.yml

```
code_cats.type.extjstime:
    class: CodeCats\PanelBundle\Form\Type\ExtjsTimeType
    tags:
        - {name: form.type, alias: extjstime}
```

My form builder:

```
...
      //not working with alias
      ->add('endedTime', 'extjstime') 
      //this one is working
      ->add('endedTime', new ExtjsTimeType())
```

my debug:

```
 php app/console container:debug code_cats.type.extjstime
[container] Information for service code_cats.type.extjstime
Service Id       code_cats.type.extjstime
Class            CodeCats\PanelBundle\Form\Type\ExtjsTimeType
Tags
    - form.type                      (alias: extjstime)
Scope            container
Public           yes
Synthetic        no
Required File    -
```

**Updated**
my form builder is:

```
namespace CodeCats\PanelBundle\Form\Type;


class ExtjsTimeType extends AbstractType {


    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'extjstime';
    }
}
```

Comment: Verify that  ExtjsTimeType::getName() returns 'extjstime';

Comment: What about using `->add('endedTime', 'extjstime')`?

Comment: When I use extjs time I have: Could not load type "extjstime", maybe alias not working?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>1</kbd> Use alias

```
services:
    code_cats.type.extjstime:
        class: CodeCats\PanelBundle\Form\Type\ExtjsTimeType
        tags:
            - {name: form.type, alias: extjstime}
```

<kbd>2</kbd> Add method getName()

```
<?php

namespace CodeCats\PanelBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ExtjsTimeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
       // ...
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'extjstime';
    }
}
```

Comment: The name is extjstime and I see the same error Could not load type "extjstime"

Comment: This has to work. Could you clear the cache? `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev`

Comment: Maybe its not working with factory? In my controller i create form $factory->createNamed(null, new RootType(), $ent); instead $this->createForm(new RootType(), $ent)